# Fail cypress test when 500 xhr request occurs

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

I am writing end-to-end tests for a web application in cypress and I would like cypress to fail the test if the applications sends any request with a http 500 error response.

I am using cypress in version 3.1.5. I already tried the following, but I get an promise error.

```
    cy.server();
    cy.route({
      url: '**',
      onResponse: (xhr) => {
        cy.log(xhr);
      }
    });
```

I hope to find a more elegant solution to this problem, because this sounds to me like a pretty standard use-case.

Answer (score 3):

Try using below code refer [doc](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Using-the-yielded-object)

```
  cy.intercept('**').as('all')

  cy.wait('@all').its('response.statusCode').should('not.be.oneOf', [500])
```

OR

Checking status code using - *should('be.oneOf', [200,300])*

```
  cy.wait('@all').its('response.statusCode').should('be.oneOf', [200,300])
```

Comment: is there anyway to restrict to XHR requests?

Comment: You can try https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Routing

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a Cypress version that supports `intercept` (`v7.x.x` or later), then you can do this in your test file:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.intercept('**', request => {
        request.on('response', function (response) {
          expect(response.statusCode).is.lessThan(500); // Test will fail if an 500 error happen
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's some canonical way, but you can monkey-patch the `XMLHttpRequest` API and throw on `>= 500` status responses.

If your app is using Fetch API, SendBeacon, or something else, you can do something similar.

```js
// put this in support/index.js
Cypress.on('window:before:load', win => {
    const origSend = win.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    win.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
        // deferring because your app may be using an abstraction (jquery),
        // which may set this handler *after* it sets the `send` handler
        setTimeout(() => {
            const origHandler = this.onreadystatechange;
            this.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if ( this.readyState === 4 && this.status >= 500 ) {
                    throw new Error(`Server responded to "${this.url}" with ${this.status}`);
                }
                if ( origHandler ) {
                    return origHandler.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            };
            return origSend.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    };
});
```

WTBS, this is not gonna be very useful because you app may want to handle that `500` instead, while this will prevent it.

Better solution is to make sure you app simply throws unhandled 500 responses.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an error inside the on request, that should work.

```
cy.server();
cy.route({
  url: '**',
  onResponse: (xhr) => {
    if(xhr.status === 500) {
        throw new Error('Failing test caused by a unhandled request with status 500')
    }
    cy.log(xhr);
  }
})
```